# Autofac not always resolving my dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

When I build my projects in my Visual Studio 2013 Professional development environment, there are times that my repositories in my controllers are all null because autofac is not resolving them properly. This happens about 30% of the time.

Here is the Autofac Initialization Code that I use:

```
public class AutofacConfig
{
    public static void ConfigureAutofac()
    {
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource()); 
        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
               .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .InstancePerRequest();

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

Most of the time when I REBUILD the project or exit and come back it the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using assembly scanning to load your dependencies. This is a known behavior of IIS and it is explain in Autofac documentation : [Why aren’t my assemblies getting scanned after IIS restart?](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/iis-restart.html#why-aren-t-my-assemblies-getting-scanned-after-iis-restart)

> When hosting applications in IIS all assemblies are loaded into the `AppDomain` when the application first starts, but when the `AppDomain` is recycled by IIS the assemblies are then only loaded on demand.
>
> To avoid this issue use the `GetReferencedAssemblies()` method on `System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager` to get a list of the referenced assemblies instead:
>
> ```
> var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>();
> ```
>
> That will force the referenced assemblies to be loaded into the `AppDomain` immediately making them available for module scanning.

Comment: Cyril, Thank you. This has completely resolved my issue. I just needed to add .ToArray() to the end for my case but everything has worked perfectly for the past several weeks.